# Ambiguous English sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

**I felt guilty cheating on my wife**

The sentence looks so ambiguous

Possible meaning 1: i felt guilty as i cheated on my wife

Possible meaning 2: i felt guilty while i was cheating on my wife

I just want to be sure which possible meaning fits for the sentence at first sight? which one to pick?

Comment: ya dead either way, so it doesn't matter...

Comment: Distinctly on an account of a spontaneous and mindless insight on my first reading of the sentence, the context which was immediately bourne from my mind was that the individual stating that sentence was "guilty" as he/she was physically "cheating" on his/her wife. Now, whence it came to be that mindless interpretation began to fade away and the intellectual insight of the mind commenced and began to dissect this sentence, thereon I began to reconsider that the sentence refers to the "guilty" result and aftermath of what that individual, who had cheated in past circumstances, was contemplating